# Reducing space between bottom legend towards edge of the paper in R plot

Tags: r, plot

Below is 2x2 bar plot figures. Notice that there is a large space between the legend at the bottom left to the end of the pages. How can I reduce that?

Sure, I can do manual cropping. But since there are many figures to be generated, it's much more preferable to deal with it automatically.

[image]

The figure is generated with this code:

```
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1563769/plain/",header=TRUE)
pdf(file="Temp.pdf",height=9,width=6);


colnames(dat) <- c("Method", "Metric", "error 0%", "error 1%", "error 2%", "error 4%")


# Define layout
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,5),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE))
par(omi=c(0,0.3,0,0.3))
barcols <- c("#D8B365","#5AB4AC")

# Generate some plots
sapply(3:6,
  function(x) {
    par(las=2);
    bp <- barplot(matrix(dat[,x],nrow=2,byrow=TRUE),beside=TRUE,col=barcols,border=NA)
    title(main=names(dat[x]),cex.main=1.0,font.main=1)
  axis(1,at=colMeans(bp),c("Method-XXX","Method-YYY"," Method-ZZZ","Method-XZZZ"," Method-XZZZY"),lwd=0,lwd.tick=1)
      abline(h=0)
  }
)

plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
par(omi=c(0.5,0,0,0))
legend("topleft",c("Precision","Recall"),box.col="white",fill=barcols,cex=1.0,border=NA)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in your layout. Your layout looks like this

[image]

But you want different heights for each row using the `heights` argument, e.g.

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,5),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE), heights=c(2,2,1))
```

which will give you this

[image]

Now, your legend does not occupy that much space anymore. You might need to tweak the margins a bit adding a `par(mar=c(0,1,2,0))` before setting up the plot window for the legend. Then you get

[image]

**Complete Code**

```
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1563769/plain/",header=TRUE)
pdf(file="Temp.pdf",height=7,width=6);
colnames(dat) <- c("Method", "Metric", "error 0%", "error 1%", "error 2%", "error 4%")

# Define layout
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,5),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE), heights=c(2,2,.6))
par(omi=c(0,0.3,0,0.3))
barcols <- c("#D8B365","#5AB4AC")

# Generate some plots
sapply(3:6,
       function(x) {
         par(las=2);
         bp <- barplot(matrix(dat[,x],nrow=2,byrow=TRUE),beside=TRUE,col=barcols,border=NA)
         title(main=names(dat[x]),cex.main=1.0,font.main=1)
         axis(1,at=colMeans(bp),c("Method-XXX","Method-YYY"," Method-ZZZ","Method-XZZZ"," Method-XZZZY"),lwd=0,lwd.tick=1)
         abline(h=0)
       }
)

par(mar=c(0,2,2,0))
plot(NULL,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
legend("topleft",c("Precision","Recall"),box.col="white",fill=barcols,cex=1.0,border=NA)
dev.off()
```